# Images Icons are not loading in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops, cicd

I installed Jenking on Docker having following version details.
Docker version- 20.10.12
Ubuntu 22.04
Jenking version-2.346.3
Java version- build 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04

I created a pipeline and it is not loading images icons.I have attached the screenshot. Could you please let me know what is causing this issue and how can I resolve it? Thank You.[image]

Comment: What errors do you see in your Browsers' Network tab?

Comment: This may be related to https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-pipeline-plugin/pull/124

Comment: Hi, Have you found a solution for the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, the latest version of Jenkins is missing a lot of the images from within the .war file (not a clue why), that this plugin (and others) reference.

To fix it (its a bit dirty) I extracted the "images" directory from a previous version of Jenkins (iirc was 2.303.1) by changing the .war to .zip.

I then merged this old version directory in to the /opt/jenkins/war/images directory once the Jenkins service had started and the files/folders populated. Then restarted the service.

For your case though, as its a docker container, it might be worth adding these to the .war file directly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So that's it? No new updated docker for Jenkins with the complete war? It's been over 3 months since this defect. Anyone?